# Using Pro*C to access a TimesTen database

Tags: timesten, oracle-pro-c

I am trying to use Pro*C to access a TimesTen database. The code to create a table in TimesTen is

```
create table testtable(id number(4) not null primary key, ename  char(10));
```

I use Pro*C to fetch data from this table. When I use this SQL:

```
select * from testtable where ename like 'wxd'
```

I get no results. But when I use this:

```
select * from testtable where ename like 'wxd       '
```

I get the right results. I must fill enough space into the field. Is there some other way to can get the right result?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Pro*C but a characteristic of the data type you have chosen for the column. `CHAR(10)` means that the field is always 10 characters wide, even if the value you insert is shorter. The database will pad a short value with spaces which is why you had to add the extra spaces in the query.

If you want a variable length column, use `VARCHAR(10)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following which works with both CHAR and VARCHAR columns:

select * from testtable where ename like 'wxd%'

A SQL like condition usually has a wildcard.